# Composite unique constraint mongoengine not working with replicaset

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongoengine, replicaset

I am trying to enforce a unique constraint over multiple attributes using unique_with param.

```
ContentType = ('category', 'product')
PageType = ('category', 'product', 'compare', 'review')


class Content(db.Document):
    content_type = db.StringField(required=True, choices=ContentType)
    content_id = db.StringField(required=True)
    page_type = db.StringField(required=True, choices=PageType, unique_with=['content_type', 'content_id'])
    title = db.StringField()
    description = db.StringField()
    keywords = db.ListField(db.StringField())
    footer = db.StringField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Content, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This creates the indexes on my local development machine. But couldn't create the indexes on production except the default unique index on _id.

In development environment I am using a single mongo instance whereas on production I am using a replicaset of 3 instance(1 master, 1 slave and 1 arbiter).

I have also tried mannually create the indexes by the following code :

```
PageType = ('category', 'product', 'compare', 'review')
ContentType = ('category', 'product')

class Content(db.Document):
    content_type = db.StringField(required=True, choices=ContentType)
    content_id = db.StringField(required=True)
    page_type = db.StringField(required=True, choices=PageType)
    title = db.StringField()
    description = db.StringField()
    keywords = db.ListField(db.StringField())
    footer = db.StringField()
    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            'content_type',
            'content_id',
            'page_type',
            {
                'fields': ['content_type', 'content_id', 'page_type'],
                'unique': True
            }
        ]
    }

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Content, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here or there is some mistake in my code. Any help would be great.

One more piece of information : The same replica set is being used by a django application and it is able to create composite indexes. So I don't think there is a problem with the replica set configuration.

Comment: you say you couldn't create indexes in production?  why not? what error do you get? what response? what's in the logs on the server? Can you create the indexes via mongo shell connected to the same server?

Comment: Yes! I could create indexes using mongo shell connected to the same server. I havn't checked the logs on production yet.

Comment: it's unlikely there is a problem with the replica set then - there is nothing that's different about creating indexes on standalone vs replica set.  are you able to write to replica from your application at all? is there authentication turned on? maybe you're not properly connecting to replica set?

Comment: I can create the db and write & read data on replica set. Everything else is working as expected. But indexes are not created by any of the method given above. The application is not using authentication right now. So its not the issue.

Comment: How are you checking index existence before and after?  Im wondering if it actually works correctly on standalone

Comment: Firstly while running the application on local because its a unique constraint so can be verified by trying to add duplicates. Now the unique constraint is throwing error while adding duplicates on local but not on production. Secondly, I use a tool called robomongo to visualize the data and other stuff. I could see indexes on local setup but not on production.

Comment: right, understood that index *exists* on local, but are you sure this code created them?  if you try to create an index that already exists, it's a no-op.